'Multipart: Boundary not found' with React Fetch POST request, but works with Postman
I'm trying to send an image and two text fields to the express server, but it gives the error "Multipart: Boundary not found".
    const handleFileUpload = async () => {
    if (!selectedFile) {
      Alert.alert('Ошибка', 'Выберите файл для загрузки');
      return;
    }
  
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', {
      uri: selectedFile.uri,
      type: selectedFile.type,
      name: selectedFile.fileName || 'image.png',
    });
    formData.append('title', newImageTitleFile);
    formData.append('description', newImageDescriptionFile);
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/images/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Ошибка загрузки файла');
      }
  
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Загружено:', data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Ошибка:', error);
    }
  };

I tried to remove the header 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', nothing changes.

The fetch function should send the formData object as multipart/form-data now that it contains a file. Take a look at the developer tools in your browser and look for the request. You should be able to see both the header Content-Type that described the boundary and the body with the boundary string separating each key/value.
You cannot send the files as a object (with the {}). You give the file (selectedFile.files[0]) as the value for the image data.
It is not clear from you question what the back-end expects, but this example (like your own code) will just do the multipart/form-data request.


const handleFileUpload = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  
  if (!form.selectedFile.files[0]) {
    alert('Ошибка', 'Выберите файл для загрузки');
    return;
  }

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', form.selectedFile.files[0]);
  formData.append('title', form.newImageTitleFile.value);
  formData.append('description', form.newImageDescriptionFile.value);

  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/images/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Ошибка загрузки файла');
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Загружено:', data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка:', error);
  }
};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', handleFileUpload);
<form name="form01">
  <input type="file" name="selectedFile">
  <input type="text" name="newImageTitleFile">
  <input type="text" name="newImageDescriptionFile">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



